# Can you make multiple acrobatics checks in a round to avoid or reduce the penalty for difficult terrain?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, terrain

Lets say I have a character, and all around them is difficult terrain for 100 feet in all directions. My character have an overland movement speed of 30. From one direction double moving at 20 for a total of 40 is a creature coming to kill you, and the creature is close. Ignore how the creature is moving, its coming at you and is moving faster than you can double move, so it will catch you and kill you.

Acrobatics allows you to make horizontal jumps. Since most characters are unable to jump vast distances like monks, they will be limited to 5-15 feet jumps. Since jumps count against your movement only for the distance traveled and not the type of terrain you jump over, each square you jump is beneficial. However falling prone can be fatal. Are you allowed to make repeated 5 foot jumps for easy 5 DC checks? You could then double move the whole way by making small jumps and safely out distance the creature coming to kill you.

Answer (score 2):

RAW: I don't think so; at least, not very well.

Using [Acrobatics to jump](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics/#jumping-and-falling) is done "as part of another action". A character generally gets two move actions per round (if they exchange a standard action for one, and barring shenanigans with feats/spells/items/...), so they could conceivably use both to jump, but you'd be limited to two Acrobatics checks.

Also, since the character won't have a running start, the DCs would double, so a 5 foot jump would take a DC 10 Acrobatics check. I'd also argue that, since the terrain is difficult, at least one of the "Misc. Acrobatics Modifiers" would apply (probably the "Severely Obstructed (cavern, rubble)" modifier which adds 5 to the DC; after doubling, that means it's a DC 20 Acrobatics check to jump 5 feet).

Comment: Do you have an argument for why "as part of another action" means "only once per action"?

Comment: Basically, the lack of a line like "you can make multiple Acrobatics checks to jump multiple times during your move action", compared to (say) http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics/#move-through-threatened-area that calls out the fact that you can make multiple checks to move through multiple foes' threatened areas. Also, http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics/#cross-narrow-surface doesn't help: it calls out that only one check is needed per round (so a path that alternates between wide and narrow is still just one check). Also, every other "you can do X as part of Y" is once per Y.

Comment: @minnmass Actually, the Move through  Threatened Area example is also bad - it does not explicitly say you can or need to do it more than once per round. It simply increases the DC for more opponents.  So, if you apply the same logic you are applying to jumps, you would be able to tumble through only a single threatened square per turn...

Comment: @YogoZuno: fair point; I was adding a line from 3.5 to the Pathfinder description. This GM still uses that line to clarify when the Acrobatics attempt fails and the character provokes.

Comment: @minnmass Specifically what line were you adding then?

Comment: @Fering I was adding a line from 3.5 when reading the PFSRD skill description.

Comment: @minnmass And since in many cases pathfinder copied verbatim from 3.5 I am curious what the line is since even if not copied, might still apply.

Comment: @Fering sorry, "Check separately for each opponent. Each additional enemy after the first adds +2 to the Tumble DC.", from the table here: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/tumble.htm